# Facebook Graph Post object feed Type

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Does anybody know all the possible "types" for a facebook Post object?

According to the documentation for the Post object (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) next to the "type" field it says:

> "A string indicating the type for this post (including link, photo, video)"

I've also tried looking through the fql documentation but didn't find anything there.

I tried looking through the facebook developer forum and found a similar question, but it hasn't been answered: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=348562#p348562

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/page/feed#readfields

Answer (score 27):

The

**Photo**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

**Video**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

**Link**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/

Docs say it has been deprecated, but it seems to still be an actively used post type.

**Status**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

<s>**Checkin**</s>

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

Feature was removed

<s>**Question**</s>

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/ outdated

if the access token is for an application/page, then you might be able to see

<s>**Review**</s>

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Review/ outdated

not an active page

<s>**Offer**</s>

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/offer/

feature was removed

**Event**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/

Comment: can't find type "swf" in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
but it does exist!

Comment: As of today, all swf posts I have found,  have the same fields as the video post type does except [width] and [height].

Comment: great work DMCS:) I also suggest it would be great if you/someone-else can keep it updated for any new types :)

Comment: This site is like a WIKI, please edit it and then if someone likes your edit, then it will become part of the history of revisions.  As you can see, this answer was last edited on Nov 20, 2012 by Ronny.

Comment: The "link" post type is still showing up on my feed, but their documentation says it was a feature that was removed? Not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post/) has been revised. The *type* field of a *Post* can refer to

```
enum{link, status, photo, video}
```

This contradicts the reply by [DMCS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52087/dmcs), presumably things have moved on.

I should stress that a *Post* is

```
an individual entry in a profile's feed.
```

Given this definition, the *type* field seems slightly misleading, since it refers to the content of a *Post*. I believe a *Post* of *type=link* is an individual entry in a profile's feed that contains a URL, similarly, a *Post* of *type=photo* contains a photo and *type=video* contains a video. A *Post* *type=status* contains any other content.

Answer (score 0):

there actually is (an uncomplete) list here:

[API Reference › FQL › stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream)

```
11 - Group created
12 - Event created
46 - Status update
56 - Post on wall from another user
66 - Note created
80 - Link posted
128 -Video posted
247 - Photos posted
237 - App story
257 - Comment created
272 - App story
285 - Checkin to a place
308 - Post in Group
```

and also a reverse-engineered addition [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/154511994682996/)

Comment: That's not the "type" in the context the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list for Graph v4.0 here (search for `status_type`):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/page/feed

```
The type of a status update. Values include:

added_photos
added_video
app_created_story
approved_friend
created_event
created_group
created_note
mobile_status_update
published_story
shared_story
tagged_in_photo
wall_post
```

Though these are listed for Page feed documentation, but I guess it's the same for others as well. I couldn't find it any place else. Also note `mobile_status_update` is a legacy one kept for backward compatibility. See this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/564448573658836/