# What types of posts are in a feed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I was wondering what all the possible types of posts I can expect in a feed. The documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ mentions that the type field could be link, video, and photo, but that's clearly not a comprehensive list. I know that there are at least the following possible types (because I've seen them): status, link, video, photo, checkin, note, swf, and music.

But are there more that I'm missing? Is there a complete list of these types somewhere?

I know of someone who says that they've seen event attendance and friendship acceptance posts in their home feed (from /me/feed), but I can't seem to recreate that. Are those also types of posts that I could expect?

Comment: I too would like to know all of the "type"s for a post

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/page/feed#readfields

Answer (score 8):

It appears that currently there is no official list from a FB resource.  The closest thing I could find was [a related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875869/facebook-graph-post-object-feed-type)

I would suggest reaching out to their developer community directly, and, of course, providing a link here once you've done so!

Answer (score 5):

As of 2013-12-18 the documentation says:

```
name: status_type   
description: Type of post
permissions: read_stream
Returns: One of mobile_status_update, created_note, added_photos, added_video, shared_story, created_group, created_event, wall_post, app_created_story, published_story, tagged_in_photo, approved_friend
```

[Doc reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list for Graph v4.0 here (search for `status_type`):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/page/feed

```
The type of a status update. Values include:

added_photos
added_video
app_created_story
approved_friend
created_event
created_group
created_note
mobile_status_update
published_story
shared_story
tagged_in_photo
wall_post
```

Though these are listed for Page feed documentation, but I guess it's the same for others as well. I couldn't find it any place else. Also note that `mobile_status_update` is a legacy one kept for backward compatibility. See this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/564448573658836/